# Update with Angular and Redux fails

Tags: angular, redux, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, updates

When I try to update a baby with Angular 5 and Redux I get the following error:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText:
>   "OK", url:
>   "http://angular2api2.azurewebsites.net/api/internships/5ad309337cbda3002a7e92e0",
>   ok: false, …} SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (...)

I have done create and get operations as well in the same files, which are working fine, so I am only posting the relevant code bits.

edit-baby.ts:

```
 this.usersActions.updateBaby(baby);
    this.usersService.updateBaby(baby).subscribe(result => {
      console.log("from ws", result);
    });
```

users.action.ts :

```
 updateBaby(baby: Baby): void {
        console.log(baby);
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({
            type: UsersActions.UPDATE_BABY,
            payload: baby
        });
    }
```

users.reducer.ts:

```
 case UsersActions.UPDATE_BABY:
            let index = state.babies.findIndex(baby => { return baby._id === action.payload._id });
            return tassign(state, { babies: [...state.babies.slice(0, index), action.payload, ...state.babies.slice(index + 1)] });
```

users.service.ts

```
 updateBaby(baby: Baby) {
        const httpOptions = {
            // responseType: 'text',
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // 'Authorization': 'my-auth-token' // If you use auth.
            })
        };
        baby.userType = 'baby'
        baby.dataClient = 'Sebastian';
        return this.http.put("http://angular2api2.azurewebsites.net/api/internships/" + baby._id, baby, httpOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Judging by the error message, you have malformed JSON. Have you looked at that to see if there are any issues with it?

Comment: where should I look ?

Comment: I guess I would start be doing a `console.log(baby);` before the `put` call in the `updateBaby` function. Then try a `console.log(JSON.stringify(baby));` to see if anything looks off.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does actually updates the object it just gives me the error instead of the result, which should be the updated object.

Comment: That makes me think that the JSON coming from the API is messed up. Not sure what you would need to do to find what is causing that.

Comment: I notice you have the responseType option commented out in the code. Is the API returning JSON or text. If it is text, then that could explain the error. Angular expects JSON by default.

Comment: it is uncommented so that cannot be the issue.

Comment: I have no idea what can be wrong, my createBaby is exact the same code beside the reducer and it works just fine. I did the console.log in both functions to compare them and the output it looks also the same.